# Matching input to mask

Tags: php, input, preg-match, mask

I need a little help I want to check if input matchs with the mask

Mask is this: 12.345.678/9012-34 (xx.xxx.xxx/xxxx-xx)

What I've tried till now is this

```
$string = '12.345.678/9012-34';

if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}$/', $string)) {
     echo 'Doesnt match the mask!';
}
```

It didn't work out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` and `.` literals you want to match, as you're using the former for the regex delimiter and the `.` has special meaning in a regex (generally to match all chars except `\n`).

```
if(!preg_match('/^\d{2}.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}$/', $string)) {
     echo 'Doesnt match the mask!';
}
```

I also used `\d` instead of `[0-9]` as it's less to read and comprehend and they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would change it:

```
/^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}$/
```

1) You can use `\d` shortcut for digits:

```
/^\d{2}.\d{3}.\d{3}/\d{4}-\d{2}$/
```

2) Dot (period) is a special character and matches any character, so you need to escape it.

```
/^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}/\d{4}-\d{2}$/
```

3) Forward slash is your delimiter, so it should be escaped inside; alternatively, use a different delimiter:

```
/^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}$/

#^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}/\d{4}-\d{2}$#
```

Comment: Thank you a lot too. But in each version of yours I've got this error: Unknown modifier '\'

Comment: @Ghostology It's because I explained it step-by-step :) anything after step 3 works.